# TCL des: Return encrypted phrase in standard ascii characters

Tags: encryption, ascii, tcl, des

I'm using DES in TCL to encrypt some phrases and I want to store those encrypted phrases in some ascii files which I need to manipulate easily. Therefore, I would like the "encrypted phrase" to be constituted only of standard ascii characters (preferentially with no spaces).

I'm using something like this to ecrypt:

```
set encrypted [ DES:des -dir encrypt -key "abcdefgh" "This_phrase" ]
```

I would like "encrypted" to be a standard ascii code, not something that,
as it happens, may even brake my terminal if displayed.

Thank you very much.
Leandro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could either replace all characters that might have a special meaning (everything except a-zA-Z0-9 etc) or encode it with e.g. base64.

```
set encrypted [base64::encode -wrapchar {} [DES:des -dir encrypt -key abcdefgh "This_phrase"]]
```

You need to strip the extra layer (base64, escape sequence encoding or whatever you used to convert the binary data to ascii) if you want to decode it.

Comment: Thank you very much, the "base64" encoding worked beautifully.

Comment: The `-hex` option to `DES::des` is another option. It's more verbose though, as it uses a smaller alphabet than base64.